# Django Tenant and Django Guardian configuration settings.py

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I have been experiencing issues configuring Django Tenant and Django Guardian. I want to separate users per schema. Where should I put Guardian and how should I configure it? So far I also tried switching it from TENANT_APP  to SHARED_APP (I get a different error something to do with other prerequisites, auth) and I get an error(below). An alternative that work well instead of guardian would also be appreciated.

```
SHARED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',
    'myapp.clients',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'custom_user',
    'myapp.users',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'guardian',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.accounting',
    'myapp.budget',
    'myapp.enterprise',
    'myapp.payables',
    'myapp.receivables',
    'rest_framework_nested',
    'solo',
    'rest_framework_swagger',    
)
```

This is the error I get when I run python manage.py migrate_schemas:

```
relation "users_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."phone_number", "users_user"."email2" FROM "users_coo...
```

This happens as soon as I add 'guardian' in TENANT_APPS

and when I add it in SHARED_APPS, I get this:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist
```

But this can be fixed with django.contrib.admin, the problem is that I want permissions to be specific to my tenant application

Additional Configuration:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)
```

Looking at the log I found out that django guardian creates an anonymous user

```
File "/home/myaccount/workspace/enterprise-api/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 192, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/myaccount/workspace/enterprise-api/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/guardian/management/__init__.py", line 33, in create_anonymous_user
    User.objects.get(**lookup)
  File "/home/myaccount/workspace/enterprise-api/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myaccount/workspace/enterprise-api/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 381, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/myaccount/workspace/enterprise-api/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 240, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/myaccount/workspace/enterprise-api/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
```

Is there a way to tell guardian to wait for a tenant database?

Answer (score 1):

```
SHARED_APPS = (
    #tenant requirements
    'tenant_schemas',
    'myapp.clients',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'myapp.users',
    'guardian',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'rest_framework',
)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'custom_user',
    'coopmsapi.users',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'guardian',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'myapp',
    'myapp.accounting',
    'myapp.budget',
    'myapp.enterprise',
    'myapp.payables',
    'myapp.receivables',
    'rest_framework_nested',
    'solo',
    'rest_framework_swagger',    
)
```

After multiple attempts this is what ended up working. I also had to perform migrations several migrations of the apps SHARED OR TENANT initially otherwise django-tenant won't pick up automatically that it needs to create certain tables when it creates a new schema.